# Error System.IO.FileNotFoundException al hacer debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, configuración, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto para una api web en .net core utilizando visual studio 2017. Tengo un archivo llamado connections.js el cual esta fisicamente ubicado en el mismo directorio del archivo appsettings.json. Cuando hago un debug del proyecto en mi equipo el archivo se lee correctamente. Sin embargo otra persona del grupo de desarrolladores clonó el proyecto en su equipo y al hacer el debug se genera un error indicando que no encuentra el archivo.  Al ver la ruta, esta apuntando a "C:\Program Files\IIS Express", mientras a mi me apunta a "D:\Trabajo\Desarrollos\WebApi\Api"

Ese es el metodo con el que abro y leo el archivo y simplemte le envio el nombre como parametro.

```
public List<Connection> readConnections(string filePath)
        {
            List<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();  
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                connections.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Connection>>(json));
            }

            return connections;
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que esto debe ser por la configuracion del IDE pero no he podido solucionarlo.

Comment: De donde obteneis el `filePath` que le enviais a la función `readConnections`? Seguramente venga de ahí el problema y no de la función de lectura

Comment: Simplemente hago el llamado asi :  var conexiones = fileService.readConnections("connections.json");

Comment: Como hicisteis el Clone del proyecto? Por el repositorio?

Comment: Es posible que la propiedad "*Directorio de ejecución*" de tu configuración de depuración esté apuntando a una ruta absoluta en lugar de a una ruta relativa. Consultad vuestros respectivos `string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`

Comment: Si, el clone se hizo con git.

Comment: Por la imagen, veo que el archivo connection.json lo tienes sólo en tu equipo (tiene pendiente la subida a tu repositorio).
Tendrías que subir ese archivo al repositorio y desde ahí sincronizar el otro desarrollador.

Comment: parece que Application.ExecutablePath no aplica para net core 2.2

Comment: Esto es problema de IDE. El esta ejecutando en otra carpeta y por eso no ve el archivo. el Tema es que ese archivo deberia ir con el ejecutable siempre, entonces lo que tienen es un problema de deploy. Ese archivo, esta para ser deployado con el exe? si no es asi, deberia estarlo